# How to get the total number of leads in marketo using an api?

Tags: marketo

I'm trying to get the total number of leads in marketo and verify with another exported place using api, is it possible with a single api call to marketo to get the total lead count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The API call sequence for getting all leads (ie: "Bulk Export") requires a few API calls (auth, start a job, enqueue the job, ping the job status, etc...). Then, after getting the file, you'd have to process and count the leads. This can take around 4-5 minutes for even a small database (just due to the job process).

Comment: That is one thing, I solved my problem using multiple API calls to the marketo website.